# How to get all this results in one mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to output 5 numbers from MySQL. It must be in one query.

I have a table called recursos_humanos.

The first number I need it's a SUM of column 'monto' for each row in recursos_humanos that is assigned to one specific proyect.

Here is how you get all the 'monto' for each row.

```
SELECT `recursos_humanos`.`monto` 
  FROM `recursos_humanos`,
       `recursos_asignados` 
 WHERE `recursos_humanos`.`id`=`recursosh_asignados`.`recursoID` 
   AND `recursosh_asignados`.`proyectoID`=’1’
```

The second number I need is from table "recursos". I want the SUM of column 'monto' for each row in "recursos" that is assigned to one specific proyect (yeah, the same as the first but the difference is that you don't need an inner join to get the values)

Here is how you get all the 'monto' for each row in 'recursos'

```
SELECT `recursos`.`monto` 
  FROM `recursos` 
 WHERE proyecto='1'
```

The third number is first number + second number + 'mano_de_obra'.

You get 'mano_de_obra' with this query:

```
SELECT `proyecto`.`mano_de_obra` 
  FROM `proyecto` 
 WHERE `did`='1'
```

The forth number is 'mano_de_obra' so yo get it as I told you in the third point.

The last number is: third number % forth number

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: For clarification, you want all five numbers to print as if they are the results of a single query? `UNION` Would be good for this, not necessarily does everything have to be done in a single SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your basic queries are correct, if you just use some [Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) and the good old fashion [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) the solution is simple.

Variables will make it easier for us to hang on to numbers we did in the past like for the third case where the number is equal to the first + second + another and the last case where it is the third number % fourth.

Using the `UNION` statement will combine the results of multiple `SELECT` statements into a single result.

I noticed in your provided SQL you didn't use `SUM()` after you found the correct column. I have added where I thought it was necessary.

```
SET @One = (SELECT SUM(`recursos_humanos`.`monto`)
    FROM `recursos_humanos`,`recursos_asignados` 
    WHERE `recursos_humanos`.`id`=`recursosh_asignados`.`recursoID` 
    AND `recursosh_asignados`.`proyectoID`=’1’);

SET @Two = (SELECT SUM(`recursos`.`monto` )
    FROM `recursos` 
    WHERE proyecto='1');

SET @Four = (SELECT `proyecto`.`mano_de_obra` 
    FROM `proyecto` 
    WHERE `did`='1');

SET @Three = (@Four + @One + @Two);

SET @Five = (SELECT MOD(@Three, @Four));

SELECT @One
UNION ALL
SELECT @Two
UNION ALL
SELECT @Three
UNION ALL 
SELECT @Four
UNION ALL
SELECT @Five
```